# How Do I fix an UnboundLocalError in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
todolist = []

def add_item(item):
    todolist =  todolist + [item]

def main():

    add_item(1)

    print(todolist)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am trying to make a function called add_item() which works like append() and I am not allowed to use any built in functions. I keep getting an UnboundLocalError. How would I fix this?

Comment: Your constraints are weird. All operators including object creation are effectively built in functions, and Python is an imperative language to the degree that even `def` is an executable statement. `global` is a rare exception in that it's a declarative directive for the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you fix the local variable issue, your code doesn't behave like list.append. append operates by stateful side effect, mutating the list it was run on; your code created a new list and assigned a name. The only way I can think of to mutate a list that way without using a named method is a [slice assignment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists):

```
def myappend(intolist, newitem):
    intolist[len(intolist):] = [newitem]
```

But this obviously uses the `len` built in function, and the assignment is translated into a [setitem](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__) call. It's possible to avoid using len, by using implicit bool and getitem calls. But the calls are still there; basically, only a program that performs no operations can run without calling built in functions.

Comment: Hey I just made a function call size() that returns the size of the list instead of using len, and thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Because the statement `todolist =  todolist + [item]`, which is an assignment statement that creates a local variable `todolist` hides the global variable with the same name. So you have to specify that the variable is in global scope using the keyword [`global`](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_global_vs_local_variables.php).

```
def add_item(item):
    global todolist
    todolist =  todolist + [item]
```

When you use `append()`,

```
 todolist.append(item)
```

there is no assignment operation, hence no variable is created and the variable in the global scope is used.

Comment: Is there any other was of doing it, without using global? The program must be completely imperative.

Comment: @blazing use `append()` instead of `+`.

Comment: That would make it not completely imperative though, because append calls from the List class.

Comment: @blazing other way is, you could pass the list `todolist` as an argument to the function.

Comment: The list.append method is [imperative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming). OO, imperative and procedural are all coexisting [programming paradigms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_paradigm).

Answer (score -1):

Check the code below:

```
todolist = []

def add_item(item):
    global todolist
    todolist = todolist + [item]

def main():
    add_item(1)
    print(todolist)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You don't need the global statement if you use append.

Comment: oh.. my bad. thanks for correcting.

Comment: This uses append and the question says trying to make a function that works like append.